# Application Authenticity is not getting enabled

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using Worklight 6.2 consumer edition. When I deploy my app, following warning flashes on server console:

```
[WARNING ] FWLSE0259W: Application authenticity protection is not being performed within the Worklight Development Server. In order to fully test Application authenticity protection, deploy the application to a non-development Worklight Server (i.e. external Worklight Server). [project MyProject].
```

I am using Web Sphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1 server. Pls advise how to make this warning make go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, if you are trying to test Application Authenticity Protection in Worklight Studio (the Eclipse development environment of Worklight), Authenticity protection is not supposed to work.

To test Application Authenticity in Worklight 6.2, you must deploy Worklight using IBM Installation Manager to your Application Server (WAS, Liberty, Tomcat), as well as your .war, .wlapp, .adapters, etc... and set it up in Worklight Console belonging to this instance of Worklight.

Only then should it work.

Comment: even if I deploy everything from ant script?

Comment: Ant's fine as well, as long as it is NOT in the Eclipse Worklight Studio plug-in. Follow the documentation.

Comment: Actually I was running ant script from eclipse ant view. shall I run it from command line?

Comment: Prerak, you cannot use Worklight Studio to test authenticity. There is documentation. Please read it: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html?lang=en

Comment: I tried this using command line but getting error. I have created another post for that. Can you take a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554835/failed-to-create-task-or-type-war-builder-in-worklight-6-2