# failed to create task or type war-builder in worklight 6.2

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using workklight 6.2 and wrote following ant task to build war file on linux machine command line.

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="build-war">        
    <war-builder projectfolder="${basedir}"
                 destinationfolder="bin/"
                 warfile="bin/MyProject.war"
                 classesFolder="classes-folder"/>
</target>
```

When I execute the task with following command "**ant -f /opt/MyWS/MyProject/build.xml "build-war**" it gives me following error :

```
Problem: failed to create task or type war-builder
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

**ANT_HOME** is set to "**/opt/IBM/Worklight/tools/apache-ant-1.8.4**". When I execute the same task in eclipse, it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the path to the jar file is not set correctly (you missed the root slash):

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: Does the file `/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-builder.jar` contain the file `com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties`? And does the latter file define the task `war-builder`?

Comment: This is the documentation I am following : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html

Comment: Ok, but you still didn't answer my questions... Did you check that the jar file exists under `/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-builder.jar`?

Comment: Yes. Jar file exist there in path and it contains default.properties file also.